# Show difference of two dataframes on particular column

Tags: python, pandas

Given two dataframes like below, how can I create a third one like `desired_output`?

It should show the difference between the amount for cost center from `df1` and the amount for cost center from `df2`, for each cost center listed in either `df1` or `df2` (default amount for `df1` should be 0 then).

So for example the first amount in `desired_output` is calculated like this: 100 - (50 + 150) = -100.

Please also note that the cost center and amount columns are named differently in each df.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'cost_center': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 5],
    'amount': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 500, 500, 300],
}

d2 = {
    'cc': [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 7],
    'a': [50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 150, 750],
}

desired_output = {
    'cost_center': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'df_amount_minus_df2_amount': [-100, 700, 300, 250, 1050, -350, -1200],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

Comment: How did you get your expected output? Could you explain for cost_center 1 for example?

Comment: have a look at pandas joining/ merging dataframes on specific columns:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging

Comment: @Erfan: sorry, for CC 1 it should be "-100": 100 - (50 + 150).

Comment: Add the logic in your question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want `groupby().sum()` of each dataframe, and then finde the difference:

```
common_index = sorted(list(set(df.cost_center.unique()).union(set(df2.cc))))

sum1 =  df.groupby('cost_center').amount.sum().reindex(common_index, fill_value=0) 
sum2 = df2.groupby('cc').a.sum().reindex(common_index, fill_value=0)

sum1-sum2
```

gives:

```
cost_center
1    -100
2     700
3     300
4     250
5    1050
6    -350
7   -1200
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not the only solution, but an option using `groupby().sum()` and merging the dataframes, then calculating the difference:

```
df3 = (df.groupby('cost_center', as_index=False).sum()
         .merge(df2.groupby('cc', as_index=False).sum(),
                left_on='cost_center', right_on='cc', how='outer')
         .fillna(0))
df3['diff'] = df3['amount'] - df3['a']
df3

   cost_center  amount   cc       a    diff
0          1.0   100.0  1.0   200.0  -100.0
1          2.0   700.0  0.0     0.0   700.0
2          3.0   300.0  0.0     0.0   300.0
3          4.0   400.0  4.0   150.0   250.0
4          5.0  1300.0  5.0   250.0  1050.0
5          0.0     0.0  6.0   350.0  -350.0
6          0.0     0.0  7.0  1200.0 -1200.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about different way

```
df2.columns=df.columns
pd.concat([df,df2.assign(amount=-df2.amount)]).groupby('cost_center').sum()
Out[234]: 
             amount
cost_center        
1              -100
2               700
3               300
4               250
5              1050
6              -350
7             -1200
```